# ASP.NET web app not working in German PCs

Tags: c#, asp.net

I´m quite newbie with ASP.NET and I would appreciate any help.

I have a web app deployed on a server and it crashes only for some employees in the LAN, which curiosly all have German PCs.

I have some problems in my company to do a Remote Debugging of the Server and I have tried with ELMAH but I dont get any info of the bug because this app is launched when you click on a button on the web page, but it´s not displayed on it.

In those German PCs, the app starts but after a few seconds, a pop-up window is displayed saying that there´s an error and it crashes.

I thought it was a Localization issue and I added this to the Web.config:

```
<globalization uiCulture="en" culture="en-GB" />
```

But still not working

Any idea?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Exactly what error are your receiving?

Comment: What _app_? I thought it is an ASP.NET Web-Application.

Comment: Probably `ToString()` or `Parse` on floating point numbers.

Comment: what is crash ? the browser or the server ?

Comment: This doesn't sound like an ASP.NET problem. Find out what that button launches - is it an exe file, a Flash or Silverlight plugin, a Java applet or application or some third party or custom ActiveX control.

Comment: try catching the exception in global.asax in the corresponding handler and logging it

Comment: if he have the server, he can just look the event viewer

Comment: yeah, should probably check the Application event log

Comment: Web application, right? What is the "it" that crashes? The entire browser?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. What it crashes is an exe file that it´s launched when you click on a button. Could I catch the exception in the Event Viewer at the server with an app like that? I was about to do a Remote Debugging with another client machine, because having an exe file wouldn´t be exactly a web app, right?